# panic: unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock: no such file or directory-not resolve

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am running a fabric network available on [this github repo](https://github.com/noorkhan-92/supply-network). the orderer get exit instantly with the following error from `docker logs orderer`.
*panic: unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock: no such file or directory*

#### System specifications:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64 bit
Hyperledger Fabric: 2.3
docker: 19.03.8

### **orderer configuration from docker-compose.yaml**

```
networks:
  supplychain:

services:
  orderer.supplychain.com:
    container_name: orderer.supplychain.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.3.1
    dns_search: .
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      # in /var/hyperledger/.. var is replaced with /etc/ here and in volumes as well
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAP=/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis_block.pb
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_METRICS_PROVIDER=prometheus
      - ORDERER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8443
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=1050
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 1050:1050
      - 8443:8443
    networks:
      - supplychain
    volumes:
      - ../channel-artifacts/genesis_block.pb:/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis_block.pb
      - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/supplychain.com/orderers/orderer.supplychain.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/supplychain.com/orderers/orderer.supplychain.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
```

### **Complete docker log from orderer**

```
2021-04-17 03:18:15.402 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 001 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2021-04-17 03:18:15.402 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 002 Orderer config values:
    General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    General.ListenPort = 1050
    General.TLS.Enabled = true
    General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
    General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
    General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    General.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
    General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
    General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
    General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
    General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
    General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
    General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
    General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
    General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
    General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
    General.GenesisMethod = "file"
    General.GenesisFile = ""
    General.BootstrapMethod = "file"
    General.BootstrapFile = "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock"
    General.Profile.Enabled = false
    General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
    General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
    General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
    General.BCCSP.Default = "SW"
    General.BCCSP.SW.Security = 256
    General.BCCSP.SW.Hash = "SHA2"
    General.BCCSP.SW.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
    General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
    General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
    FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
    FileLedger.Prefix = ""
    Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
    Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
    Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
    Kafka.Verbose = true
    Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
    Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
    Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
    Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
    Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 3
    Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
    Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
    Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
    Operations.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0:8443"
    Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
    Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    Metrics.Provider = "prometheus"
    Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
    Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
    Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
    Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
    ChannelParticipation.Enabled = false
    ChannelParticipation.MaxRequestBodySize = 1048576
    Admin.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:9443"
    Admin.TLS.Enabled = false
    Admin.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Admin.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Admin.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Admin.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = true
    Admin.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Admin.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
2021-04-17 03:18:15.410 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 003 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2021-04-17 03:18:15.416 UTC [blkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 004 Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains
panic: unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock: no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/bootstrap/file.(*fileBootstrapper).GenesisBlock(0xc0001aa390, 0xc0001aa390)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/bootstrap/file/bootstrap.go:39 +0x1c0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:128 +0x1eac
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
2021-04-18 00:44:11.125 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 001 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2021-04-18 00:44:11.125 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 002 Orderer config values:
    General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    General.ListenPort = 1050
    General.TLS.Enabled = true
    General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
    General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
    General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    General.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
    General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
    General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
    General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
    General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
    General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
    General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
    General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
    General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
    General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
    General.GenesisMethod = "file"
    General.GenesisFile = ""
    General.BootstrapMethod = "file"
    General.BootstrapFile = "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock"
    General.Profile.Enabled = false
    General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
    General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
    General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
    General.BCCSP.Default = "SW"
    General.BCCSP.SW.Security = 256
    General.BCCSP.SW.Hash = "SHA2"
    General.BCCSP.SW.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
    General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
    General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
    FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
    FileLedger.Prefix = ""
    Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
    Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
    Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
    Kafka.Verbose = true
    Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
    Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
    Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
    Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
    Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 3
    Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
    Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
    Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
    Operations.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0:8443"
    Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
    Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    Metrics.Provider = "prometheus"
    Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
    Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
    Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
    Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
    ChannelParticipation.Enabled = false
    ChannelParticipation.MaxRequestBodySize = 1048576
    Admin.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:9443"
    Admin.TLS.Enabled = false
    Admin.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Admin.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Admin.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Admin.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = true
    Admin.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Admin.TLS.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
2021-04-18 00:44:11.133 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 003 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
panic: unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock: no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/bootstrap/file.(*fileBootstrapper).GenesisBlock(0xc000114bf0, 0xc000114bf0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/bootstrap/file/bootstrap.go:39 +0x1c0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:128 +0x1eac
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```

Comment: Your genesis block file location is `/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis_block.pb`, and you have set it up, but in the actual log you can see that it was recognized as `/etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock`. Because of this, we can see that the environment variable setting is wrong and that `ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAP` is not correct. In other words, it seems to be a simple typo. Replace it with `ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAP_FILE`.

Comment: There is a typo in my comment.
NOT `ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAP_FILE`,
`ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPFILE`.

Comment: I don't know exactly whether the version 2.3 of the fabric has changed, but there are two types of channels in the fabric up to version 2.2. The first is the system-channel (genesis.block) of the entire network, and the second is the channel to which organizations participate.

Comment: The system-channel works right away by making a block with configtxgen and planting it in the orderer to start up the network. On the other hand, in a channel, a transaction that creates a channel is created with configtxgen, and after the transaction is requested/registered in the blockchain network (system-channel), peers join with the created block.

Comment: In other words, two different templates and commands (parameters) are required. If you look at your configtx.yaml file, the system-channel template is a normal channel template, and it is wrong. Please refer to the link and correct it. [fabric/2.3/configtx.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-2.3/sampleconfig/configtx.yaml)

Comment: Refer to the `SampleDevModeEtcdRaft` item.
In addition, new questions must be newly written as questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah it was my fault the panic gone now. But now it shows another following error: panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: the block isn't a system channel block because it lacks ConsortiumsConfig You can see configtx.yaml file profile section from given github link. @myeongkilkim

Comment: Yeah it was problem in my configtx.yaml file. It was not in standard format especially i was missing Consortium portion of profile section. Now i have updated and working fine. Will push to GitHub to update old one, other people can see there.